# max latest null value sql

Tags: sql, null

I am experiencing the following problem. I have a table in this table I same history. Due to an error, I'm interested in finding the following information.

The latest record for a user where column1 value is null and the modifiedon date is the newest for this user. The problem is the table contains more records where the modifiedon is not null for this user and mutated after the date I'm looking for.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Sample data:

```
    personid    FreeField01         ModifiedOn
    1           0004998             15-10-2019 11:48:19
    1           NULL                20-10-2019 01:53:39
    1           0004998             22-10-2019 14:58:44
    1           0004998             22-10-2019 14:58:44
    1           NULL                23-10-2019 07:52:46
    1           0004998             23-10-2019 17:16:45
```

So for this user, I'm not interested in any record and should be excluded from the result because the modified on datetime should be before 29-10 and before that date the freefield01 value should be null and modifiedon should be the latest.

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: Please provide a sample of data as well as expected result and the query you tried...

Comment: please see my update

Comment: So which DBMS product **are** you using?

Comment: Dude, please provide your expected result based on your sample above !

Comment: @Gosfly: For the sample data the expected result is empty. OP has already said so. The person's newest row doesn't match the condition "before October 29 and value is null".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below script-

```
WITH CTE
AS(
    SELECT personid,MAX(ModifiedOn) MD
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY personid
    HAVING MAX(ModifiedOn) < '30-10-2019'
)

SELECT * FROM your_table A
INNER JOIN CTE B ON A.personid = B.personid
AND A.ModifiedOn = B.MD
AND A.FreeField01 IS NULL
```

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=86b5667927e29a1cba60f1e62c3b6a6b)

Comment: could you please see my updated post, i have added some information

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: i am using mssql

Comment: Please check my updated script. It should work for you.

Comment: thank you for your help. So i ran the query and i got some results. For example this one. But this result should be excluded because the latest result before 29-10 is not null.

        Event PersonID FreeField01 FreeField02 FreeField03 FreeField04 FreeField05 FreeField06 FreeField07 FreeField08 ModifiedOn UserID Archive
INSERTED 9 0006417 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 18-10-2019 13:35:54 6 0
UPDATED 9 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 20-10-2019 17:07:23 6 0
UPDATED 9 0006417 NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 23-10-2019 21:04:42 6 0

Comment: Check the result in DEMO link provided.

Comment: @mkRabbani: I think you have misunderstood the request. OP is not interested in the latest null row before October 29. They are interested in whether the latest row is null and before October 29.

Comment: Haha, you could just as well have used your previous query and simply moved the conditions on date and null value outside the subquery :-)

Comment: BTW: Be careful when comparing dates with strings. The DBMS may or may not be able to correctly guess what date '30-10-2019' is supposed to be. Better work with date variables `DATE '2019-10-30'` when possible. SQL Server doesn't know date literals. It is recommended to use a string in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD' in this DBMS (i.e. the same as a standard date literal without the keyword `DATE`).

Answer (score 0):

Three conditions:

1. There is no newer entry for the person.
2. The entry value is NULL.
3. The date is before 2019-10-29.

The query:

```
select *
from mytable
where not exists
(
  select *
  from mytable newer
  where newer.personid = mytable.personid
  and newer.modifiedon > mytable.modifiedon
)
and freefield01 is null
and modifiedon < date '2019-10-29'
order by personid;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think i have three conditions, the modifiedon date should be before 29-10, the freefield01 must be null and for this person it must be the newest modifiedon date. When i run your query, i get three results and there must be more.

Comment: Then please check your data. Remove the null and date conditions (2nd and 3rd condition) from the query. Thus you see each person's latest row. Check their date and value.

Comment: its making my mind spin. Cant figure out what the problem is.

Comment: You say you expect more result rows. Is there any particular person you expect in the results, but it is not there? Then select the person's rows ordered by date. Look at the latest row. Is it really a row before October 29 with a null value?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for persons where the `FreeField01` has a value of `NULL` as of a certain date.

Here is one method:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.ModifiedOn = (select max(t2.ModifiedOn)
                      from t t2
                      where t2.personid = t.personid and
                            t2.ModifiedOn <= '2019-10-29'
                     ) and
      t.FreeField01 is null;
```

EDIT:

Based on your comment, you might just want an aggregation and `having`:

```
select personid
from t
where t.ModifiedOn <= '2019-10-29'
group by person_id
having sum(case when t.FreeField01 is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: you understand correct. BUT there cant be a record after the NULL record. So if there is a NULL record for freefield01 on 21-10 , and there is a record with a value in freefield01 on 27-10 i am not interested in this user.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest query that I found might be the following if I understand your request well :

```
SELECT t.personid, t.FreeField01, MAX(ModifiedOn) FROM test t
GROUP BY personid
HAVING MAX(ModifiedOn) < '29-10-2019' AND FreeField01 IS NULL
```

[**SEE EXAMPLE HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6b518/2)

EDIT : Following below suggestions you can use this query instead :

```
SELECT t1.personid, t1.FreeField01, t1.ModifiedOn
FROM test t1
JOIN (
    SELECT t.personid, MAX(ModifiedOn) AS MaxModifiedOn FROM test t
    GROUP BY personid
    HAVING MAX(ModifiedOn) < STR_TO_DATE('29-10-2019','%d-%m-%Y')
) t2 ON (t1.personid = t2.personid AND t1.ModifiedOn = t2.MaxModifiedOn)
WHERE FreeField01 IS NULL
```

[**SEE NEW DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6b518/13)

Comment: This is invalid SQL. You are aggregating per `personid`, but access `FreeField01` in the `HAVING` clause as if there existed only one `FreeField01` value per person. The only DBMS I know of that let's you write such queries is MySQL. It silently applies `ANY_VALUE` on `FreeField01` then, i.e. arbitrarily picks one of the person's values, no matter from which row. Better set `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode, as long as you have problems with aggregation, so MySQL prevents you from writing such invalid queries.

Comment: And please don't write `MAX(ModifiedOn) < '29-10-2019'`. You are comparing a datetime with a string. Don't do this. This forces MySQL to try to convert your string to a date. This may or may not work depending on database settings. The proper expression with a date literal would be `MAX(ModifiedOn) < DATE '2019-10-29'`.

Comment: Yes, that should work. Your new query equals the query mkRabbani posted an hour ago.

Comment: @Gosfly this gives me the same result as the query thorsten provided. I get 3 rows back., if i remove the date condition i get 3 back.

Comment: @ user2633207: Which proves the queries work :-) If you expect more rows in the results, then you obviously want other criteria applied. Which? Provide an example with data where you expect a person in the result and it's not there.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help (all). So it is possible that there is person X that has a null value on 21-10 , and a 12345 on 26-10. I dont want this user in the results. I only want to see users that had a NULL on 28-10 and it is possible they have a 12345 NOW, thats fine (and expected). Edit: or a null before 28-10 and nothing after.

Comment: @user2633207: That is different. So you want to look at the latest row before October 29. If this last row has a null value, you want to show it. This is what Gordon's query does. So what's wrong with his query then? (And why didn't you tell me right away that the first condition I mention in my answer is wrong?)

Comment: the problem is, it doesnt show the expected result. I know for sure there must be more.

Comment: select t.*
from vwPersonFreeFieldHist as t
where t.ModifiedOn = (select max(t2.ModifiedOn)
                      from vwPersonFreeFieldHist t2
                      where t2.personid = t.personid and
                            t2.ModifiedOn <= '2019-10-29'
                     ) and
      t.FreeField01 is null;

If i run this, i get that personid1 in the results so it must be wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202723/discussion-between-thorsten-kettner-and-user2633207).